# Buffer.BlockCopy does not work more than one time

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, buffer, varbinary

I have a class that each time it receives buffer and it should append to a bigger byte array but it do the block copy only the first time, and then it does not copy anything
the first time buffer enters the class it copy the content in allData. but the second time it is all zero although buffer contains data.
This is my code:

```
public Boolean WriteBlobsToDB(byte[] buffer, int offset, int fileSize, string fileName, string fileType, string user, int count, int NChunks, string md5Src,int id)
{
    bool ret = false;
    int l = buffer.Length; // The buffer length is almost 2 MB
    var allData = new byte[fileSize];
    int offst = count * offset; // count is 0 the first timethen each time a new buffer comes, the value of count in count++ 

    Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, allData, offst, fileSize);
    if (count == NChunks-1 ) // NChunks is the number of how many time the buffer would be passed here 
    {               // the meaning of this if is that, when all the buffer of a file is passed then move to the database and upload the table
        File_List fl = new File_List();
        fl.FileName = fileName;
        fl.Id = id;
        fl.FileType = fileType;
        fl.MD5 = md5Src;
        fl.Data = new Binary(allData);
        try
        {
            dc.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }

    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: i don't see any loop here

Comment: there is no loop this is the class that is called from a handler every time it recieves a chunk

Comment: What are the input and outputs? You are copying data in a local variable called 'allData'.

Comment: The variable "fl" isn't defined anywhere. Is that "wfl" a typo?

Comment: In fact, I have the impression this function has a ton of unused parameters, and uses a ton of global variables. Either this function is an incomplete copy of your real code, or you're not using the concept of function parameters correctly.

Comment: Your return value is always "false". If this is an error checking mechanism, maybe that's the problem? I'd say you should default it to True and change it to False in the catch block.

Comment: @Nyerguds... I just updated, yes fl is defined. and about the parameters I use them but I have just pasted the part of code that I have this problem with.

Comment: Incomplete code like that gives a very distorted image of the issue. Not only is that piece not compilable, but you can't just assume your problem is actually in that part.

Comment: I assure you: `Buffer.BlockCopy` works just fine. The problem is in how you are using it, but we don't have enough from the context to properly assess this; a trivial reproducible example would be awesome, but: this isn't it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var allData = new byte[fileSize];
int offst = count * offset;
Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, allData, offst, fileSize);
```

Here, `allData` is of length `fileSize`. You say it works when `count` is `0` (the first time); let's consider the case when `count` is non-zero, then. You are telling it to copy `fileSize` bytes from `buffer` to `allData`, starting reading from offset `0` in `buffer`, and starting writing at offset `offset` in `allData`. We know that when `count` is non-zero, `offst` is non-zero. Since `allData` is `fileSize` bytes long, this will **always overflow the bounds** (the  end of the writing position  will be `fileSize+offst`, with `offst`  non-zero and the  array being of length `fileSize`). I expect it is raising an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` that you aren't telling us about.

Edit: actually, it is an `ArgumentException`:

> `System.ArgumentException`: Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index the end of the source collection.

Basically: either you have your parameters the wrong way around, or you're telling it to do something that will never work.

It is possible (likely?) that you intended:

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, offst, allData, 0, fileSize);
```

Comment: filesize is just the name of the variable. we are not sure how that variable is used. I think OP is using it as a length, for example. I agree with you we have little info to answer this question.

Comment: @sam yup; I'm not reading any meaning into it except that which is present in the code.  If you create an array of length `fileSize`, and try to write `fileSize` bytes into it **starting at a non-zero offset**, things aren't going to work well. It doesn't matter what `fileSize` means for that statement to be true.

Comment: This is the story. on my handler each time I receive a chunk that is part of a file. and here I want to append all the received chunks(that I call them buffer which is byte[] type)  in a byte array that is the same size as my filesize. and buffer size is 2 MB each time. so I have buffer that when you sum up their sizes is going to be equal to the filesize.

Comment: @laila that doesn't change the logic of what the code written does, though; essentially you're saying: "create an array of length 10, now write 10 values into it starting at 5, so positions... 5-14" - there *is* no position 10-14. Note also that your code isn't *appending* anything; it is **splitting** a single large buffer into multiple fragments.

Comment: @laila as a side note: unless it is the very last fragment, the data is actually discarded anyway

Answer (score 0):

You receive a chunk of bytes in `buffer[]` and you copy it in a local variable.
You are copying bytes in a local variable called `allData` that is newly created every time.

You should pass the receiver buffer`allData` to the function too.

Comment: It could be entirely valid and correct for `allData` to be local to the method, especially since this is used in the constructor for `Binary` - it would be correct for those to be independent. Sorry, but I don't think this is a helpful answer. In your defense: the question doesn't give enough information *for* a helpful answer, IMO.

Comment: @MarcGravell  Well, laila said that function is called in a loop that's somewhere else, so the full buffer being a local var and thus recreated every loop iteration does seem dodgy to me.

Comment: but even if it's the problem of initializing every time(allData) bt anyway it should copy the daya. but it does not
and also I updated to explain more

Comment: i expect a variable called alldata not to be recreated locally.

Comment: @sam as long as `allData` is referring to "all the data that makes up the logical file we know as `fileName`", then it isn't an unreasonable name; `fileContents` might be better, but... meh